# Java read only half of the web url

Tags: java

I try to read the entire source from a web page, but I receive only half or less.
It's something wrong with my code?

This is the code that I wrote:

```
public class ReadFromReuters {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ReadFromReuters rfr = new ReadFromReuters();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rfr.getConnection().getInputStream()))){
        String str;
        while((str = br.readLine()) != null){                
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }catch(IOException ioe){}         
}
public URLConnection getConnection() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    URL reuters = new URL("http://www.quickflix.com.au/browse/play");
    URLConnection conn = reuters.openConnection();        
    return conn;
}
public void splitBy(String str){

}
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that only half was read?

Comment: look at the resulted output and noticed that are too few lines returned and not the entirely information.

Comment: I don't know if this would help your case, but you shouldn't silently swallow that `IOException`. It might be telling you something important -- and this _could_ even be the cause of your problem. At the very least, you should log or print it (`e.printStackTrace()`). Better yet, you should send it up the call stack to someone who can do something useful with it (reporting an error to the user somehow, etc).

Comment: What specific information is missing? Do your results stop in the middle of the page? Does the page load some of its content via JavaScript?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?  The answer might be in an exception.

Comment: After added the printStackTrace, I got "ava.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:"

Comment: without this the code terminate normally

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code. Seems to work. I've compared the output of your code and souce code of the site with WinMerge. Result: No differences. 
Note: This site use paging! You get only the first page with this code.

Comment: sorry I put another wrong url and no exception, I still have the same prblem

Comment: Can you help me with an advice on how to get all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and rectified some error, It works fine. Try this modified code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class ReadFromReuters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        ReadFromReuters rfr = new ReadFromReuters();
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rfr.getConnection().getInputStream()));
            String str;
            while((str = br.readLine()) != null){                
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){}         
    }

    public URLConnection getConnection() throws MalformedURLException,
            IOException {
        URL reuters = new URL("http://www.quickflix.com.au/browse/play");
        URLConnection conn = reuters.openConnection();
        return conn;
    }

    public void splitBy(String str) {

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the difference between BufferedReader with limited resource and the way you wrote.If you change the link with http://www.quickflix.com.au/browse/play/newreleases the issue is still there.

Comment: @coco: Try by using Eclipse IDE with above coding. It works fine. The error in your code is "you are writing BufferedReader inside the try open brace". Try block is always followed by "{" brace and end up with "}", then it should be followed by Catch block.